# react-table is extremely slow with react-select: how to speed it up?

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-table

I have a table of editable data that's displayed with `react-table`. I'm using `react-select` for the cells. Whenever I change an entry, it takes a long time (close to a second) for the page to update. How can I speed this up?

Here's a fork of the official "editable table" example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-cdn-fcu3i?file=/src/App.js, modified to use `<Select>` instead of `<input>`.

Part of the code from that official example updates the data on blur:

```
 // We'll only update the external data when the input is blurred
  const onBlur = () => {
    updateMyData(index, id, value)
  }
```

This means that even tabbing through the elements is extremely slow. I was able to address that by adding a check in `updateMyData` to abort if the data didn't actually change:

```
const updateMyData = (rowIndex, columnId, value) => {
  if (data[rowIndex][columnId] === value) return;

  etc. // (otherwise update)
}
```

So that fixes the tabbing issue, I believe, but what about data entry? Could it be made asynchronous, for example, or would that have dangerous consequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason they use `onBlur` with inputs is to avoid re-rendering the whole table after each keystroke, with selects you don't have the same problem, so you don't need to use `onBlur` at all, just report the update in the `onChange` handler (no need to keep the value in the cell state either). Saying that, the whole solution doesn't look particularly efficient - after each change the table is re-rendered twice. I've wrapped `updateMyState` into `useCallback` and `SelectCell` in `memo`, which seems to make it a bit better, but you might want to find another approach, particularly if you have a big table. Anyways, have a look here https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-night-vymfi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much! I've learned a lot from your changes. My table isn't even very big, so I was surprised that even with a dozen rows, it was extremely slow. Now it works perfectly. I noticed that if the cells were populated, then it was impossible to switch back to the original values (e.g., if a cell starts at "kiwi" and you change to "watermelon", then you can't go back to "kiwi"; the demo I linked to didn't demonstrate this because they all start blank). That's because of `memo`, guess? I managed to fix it by putting `useState` back in.

Comment: The value is passed as a prop, so `memo` should take it into consideration, I'm not sure why it wouldn't change. If you're happy using `useState` though, it's absolutely fine. Glad I could help!