# Avoid component to rerender at state change with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a Layout component, which has a Table component, with a component Entry for each row.

Each row can be selected, so later with a button I can send all the entries to a REST service, so each time a row is selected I add it to my state.

But each time the state changes, my Layout component renders, rendering each entry of the table, that makes me lost lots of performance and time.

Is there a way to avoid rerendering the component? I'm trying to avoid using class components.

This function triggers the rendering...

```
 const checkBoxHandler = (index) => {
    
    
    const actualSelectedCheck = checks[index]

    if(!selectedChecks.includes(actualSelectedCheck)){
        setSelectedChecks(selectedChecks.concat(actualSelectedCheck))
    } else {
        const newSelectedChecks = selectedChecks.slice();
        const indexOfSelected = selectedChecks.indexOf(actualSelectedCheck)
        newSelectedChecks.splice(indexOfSelected, 1);
        setSelectedChecks(newSelectedChecks);
    }

}
```

Why am I using the selected checks as a state? Because the rest service's button only renders when there are 1 or more selected checks.

---

Mi layout component which is rerendering...

```
const fixedModal = (selectedChecks.length === 0) ? null : <RescueAdminModal selectedChecksLength={selectedChecks.length}/>;

const table =
(error === null) ? 
   (loading) ? <Spinner />
   : <RATable checkboxHandler={checkBoxHandler} checks={checks} /> : null;


return(
        <Aux>
            <div className="mb-2">Filtros por estado</div>
            <RAStates changeStateHandler={stateHandler} />
            {table}
            {fixedModal}
            <div style={{height:'6rem'}} />
        </Aux>
    )
```

My table component;

```
 const RATable = (props) => {

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <TableContainer style={{overflowX: "initial"}} className='my-5' component={Paper}>
      <Table stickyHeader className={classes.table} size="small" aria-label="a dense table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Fecha de presentación</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Bco. emisor</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Nro. Cheque</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Cta. emisora</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Importe</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Suc. Recep.</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Nro. Boleta</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Operatoria</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Fecha Rescate</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Estado</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"><b>Fec. Ingreso</b></TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center"></TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {props.checks.map((check, index) => <RACheckEntry checkboxHandler={props.checkboxHandler} check={check} index={index+"nico"}/>)}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
  );
}
```

My entry component;

```
const RACheckEntry = (props) => {
    console.log("render checkentry")
    const toggleCheckBox = () => props.checkboxHandler(props.index);

    return(
        <TableRow key={props.index}>
            <TableCell align="center" component="th" scope="row">
                {props.check.fecPresentacion}
            </TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.bcoEmis}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.nroCheque}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.ctaEmisora}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.importe}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.sucRecep}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.nroBoleta}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.oper}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.fechaRescate}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.estado}</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="right">{props.check.fecIngreso}</TableCell>
            {(props.check.estado === A_RESCATAR) ? <Checkbox onChange={() => toggleCheckBox(props.index)} color="primary"/> : null}
        </TableRow>
          
    )
```

---

EDIT after Nadia's comment:

```
const checkBoxHandler = React.useCallback(index => {
    
    
    const actualSelectedCheck = checks[index]

    if(!selectedChecks.includes(actualSelectedCheck)){
        setSelectedChecks(selectedChecks.concat(actualSelectedCheck))
    } else {
        const newSelectedChecks = selectedChecks.slice();
        const indexOfSelected = selectedChecks.indexOf(actualSelectedCheck)
        newSelectedChecks.splice(indexOfSelected, 1);
        setSelectedChecks(newSelectedChecks);
    }

}, []);
```

Comment: You should include more of your component code I think in order for it to be a reproducible example.

Comment: I just added all my JSX!

Comment: What library do your `TableContainer`, `Table`, `TableHead`, `TableBody`, `TableRow`, and `TableCell` components come from?

Comment: They're from material-ui.

Comment: I think you might be grasping at a non-issue here. A change in the state will lead to re-rendering the component (and any children that receive that state as a prop). React is in most cases smart enough to diff what changed and to then re-render only components that need it. (Edit) Also, a re-render makes sense as the changing of state may have an impact on the visual representation of the data. You could isolate the selected checks state to the `RATables` component if you don't want your whole layout component  to rerender

Comment: Each time I select a checkbox it lates like a second in get painted. Seeing console it's the time it takes to render my 80 entries.

Comment: @Ayushya tables are notoriously difficult to optimize in React, especially when there's a lot of complex business requirements that need to be baked into the UI as well.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yep totally agree but isn't a re-render based on state change expected? OP could use a virtualized list in combination with this and isolate the state to `RATables` component prevent a re-render of the whole layout

Comment: You may want to wrap `RACheckEntry` in `React.Memo`, so they only re-render when propss change (if you do that make sure `checkboxHandler` is created with `useCallback`)

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I think you could post that as the answer, I didn't even think of that

Comment: @NadiaChibrikova I used the React.memo at the RACheckEntry export (export default React.memo(RACheckEntry);) and didn't work. Can you explain me how to use the 'useCallback' ? I have no idea sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wrap `RACheckEntry` in `React.memo` (`RACheckEntry =React.memo((props) => {..})`) React will only re-render it when props change, however one of you props is a method `checkboxHandler`, I don't see where you define it, but if it is defined inside a functional component, it'll be re-created on each render, making `memo` useless. To avoid this problem React provides `useCallback` hook, if you define your handler with it it'll stay the same between renders (`const checkboxHandler= useCallback(() => { ...},[]`).

Someone had a similar problem with a different table and it seems it work for them [react-table is extremely slow with react-select: how to speed it up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66713726/react-table-is-extremely-slow-with-react-select-how-to-speed-it-up/66720220#66720220)

Update: move all manipulations with state inside setSelectedChecks callback, so you don't depend on the current state inside checkBoxHandler

```
const checkBoxHandler = React.useCallback(index => {

setSelectedChecks(selectedChecks => {
const actualSelectedCheck = checks[index]

if(!selectedChecks.includes(actualSelectedCheck)){
    return selectedChecks.concat(actualSelectedCheck)
} else {
    const newSelectedChecks = selectedChecks.slice();
    const indexOfSelected = selectedChecks.indexOf(actualSelectedCheck)
    newSelectedChecks.splice(indexOfSelected, 1);
    return newSelectedChecks;
}})
}, [checks]);
```

here's a simplified version of it https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-franklin-euzn7?file=/src/App.js

Update 2:

The reason why it didn't work initially is a combination of two factors: JavaScript closure and React immutable state. When a JavaScript function is created it is enclosed with the surrounding state (basically the viable names are replaced with the actual addresses in memory). But then, when you set state in React, you don't modify existing objects in memory, you create brand new ones. This means that `checkboxHandler` created in the first render is stuck with two empty arrays, with no way to know where current state is in memory.

To solve this problem you can either pass `checks` and `selectedChecks` as parameters to `checkboxHandler` or add them as dependencies to `useCallback`. In the later case React with re-create `checkboxHandler` each time one of the dependencies changed. Now, `checks` are fine as they are only updated once and this will result in updating all entries anyways. But if you add `selectedChecks` as a dependency, `checkboxHandler` will be recreated each time `selectedChecks` are updated, which defeats the puprose. Luckily although `checkboxHandler` has no idea where to get current state, React provides a way to access it via set state callback. If you move the logic from `checkboxHandler` to the callback there is no need for `checkboxHandler` to capture `selectedChecks`. So we are moving from

1. `checkBoxHandler` calculates new state based on `selectedChecks` captured at the moment of `checkBoxHandler` creation
2. `checkBoxHandler` passes new state to React

to

1. `checkBoxHandler` passes a method to React
2. React passes current state to that method
3. the method calculates new state based on the fresh state and passes it to React

Comment: Nadia thanks! This solved the performance problem, but now the modal is not getting updated with the selectecChecks of my state.I just add my new useCallback function to the post, is it right?

Comment: Ah, I see, it's because you modify the state, but the state is captured in the useCallback, you can change your code a little bit so you're able to update selectedChecks without re-defining the callback, but only if  `checks` are fairly stable (where are they coming from?)

Comment: At my useEffect I make a call to an API, there I populate my checks with the response.

Comment: Nadia, just try it and now each select alternates between empty array and an array with undefined consecutively.

Comment: Any chance you can make an example of this on codepen or similar?

Comment: Ah,it might be checks are null,you may need to add them as a dependency : `[checks]` at the end of the `useCallback`

Comment: Hey! I made a small example of how it can work, hope it helps.

Comment: WOW Nadia, sorry for the late answer, had no time at all day. I just copy the checkboxhandler you wrote at codesandbox and it worked!!!! There is a way you can explain me theoretically what did you do? Why did you use "setSelectedChecks" out of the logic? Why did you add checks at array dependency?

Comment: Hi Nicolas! No worries, I recon we're in different time zones. I added an explanation to the answer hope it makes sense :)